# Xvfb is properly running but i got this error: "Error: no display specified". Only when I run a selenium test from jenkins

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, jenkins, xvfb

I have a CentOS 6.5 server with jenkins and Xvfb + firefox installed and running properly. I'm trying to run some selenium tests from jenkins and i'm getting this error when i build the jenkins job:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>
> Error: no display specified

However Xvfb and firefox are properly running. The config of the job in jenkins is simple, by shell i do: java - jar test.jar (test.jar is a compiled selenium test located in that job workspace).

> **IMPORTANT**: If I do: "java -jar test.jar" just from my server (without
>   jenkins) the test run correctly.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem earlier.so just try to delete the extracted folder of your test.jar and then try your steps to run test. hopefully it will make sense.